# How to spot patterns in a multidimensional array and break down data into usable types such as Maps or Sets

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is a pretty open-ended and not a completely specific question I suppose, but I think it's a good example of what our brains can do easily that may be hard to code. A solution would be cool, but *I'm really more interested in what your would-be approach*.

This particular question is from CodeSignal's graph theory section, and asks us to write a function that determines if, from a given adjacency matrix (not important to know for this example), if a graph **resembles a bowtie**.

You can imagine a center vertex with two pairs of 'roads' (or degrees) coming off, each pair sharing an exclusive 'road' between its other two vertices.

I've done several other of these problems, but this one is of a new set consisting of specific shapes, and much easier for spotting patterns for passing input. I've used tons of Array.prototype methods to build and transform multidimensional arrays. *Each problem has taken me a pretty painful amount of time.* I'm really struggling to find an efficient way to handle this data in general.

**Here's a list of 'roads' (or degrees) as a test case.** (I've turned the adjacency matrix into an array of roads for convenience.) Each digit represents a node, or a vertex (there will only ever be five, if that's easier)...

```
[ [ '0', '1' ],
  [ '0', '2' ],
  [ '1', '0' ],
  [ '1', '2' ],
  [ '2', '0' ],
  [ '2', '1' ],
  [ '2', '3' ],
  [ '2', '4' ],
  [ '3', '2' ],
  [ '3', '4' ],
  [ '4', '2' ],
  [ '4', '3' ] ]
```

(note: the center vertex will not be specified in the array, and this is just one example.)

***Even without graph theory training we can tell within some seconds that this is a valid "bowtie".***

Note: Some of the roads are repeats but I did this on purpose... I figured if it's easier to see, it's easier to code.

We want to read from such an array and determine (return true) if the roads form a **bowtie**. |><|

I ask because I'm betting there are some features of JavaScript that I have not known to think about. I know what Maps and Sets are and I thought a Map might help, but I sort of lack the coding experience. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Is node "0" the center vertex? And the other nodes are laid out to form the bowtie shape?

Comment: the center vertex isn't specified... good question. I'll update.

Comment: It seems like everything is connected-- I don't quite see how that array represents a bowtie. Maybe a diagram would help?

Comment: the digits are nodes. '2' is connected to four other nodes, so it's the center, in this example

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Also, do you care about the "bi-directional" info, or can you delete duplicate vertices ([1,2] & [2,1] => [1,2])

Comment: no the answer won't care, it could be rewritten with no repeats, but one thing I thought is, how do I check that there are only 5 different numbers in the 0 index of each, that there are four of one of them, and two of four others. but how to extend that out into the second element of each, and do it well, is beyond me

Comment: I appreciate your interest!

Answer (score 0):

Finding algorithms to do these kinds of things efficiently can be really tricky-- I can't necessarily advise you on that piece, but I can offer some coding suggestions.

### 1) Convert Array -> Object

A plain JavaScript [`object`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp), or a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), can be a useful data type for graph stuff. They are really similar (slightly different) data types, that store things according to key-value pairs. One strategy: you could make each node into key, and an array of connected nodes into the value. This feels like a slightly more useable structure for this information. Something like this:

```js
/**
 * Convert array of arrays into object
 * where {key=node, val=[array of connected nodes]}
 */
function arrayToObj(roadsArr) {
  // start with empty object
  var obj = {};

  // iterate over each pair in roads array
  // initialize new {key: [val]} entry if none exists
  // otherwise add to existing list of values
  roadsArr.forEach(function(pair) {
    var key = pair[0];
    var val = pair[1];
    if (obj[key] === undefined) {
      obj[key] = [val];
    } else {
      obj[key].push(val);
    }
  });
  return obj;
}


roadsArr = [
  ["0", "1"],
  ["0", "2"],
  ["1", "0"],
  ["1", "2"],
  ["2", "0"],
  ["2", "1"],
  ["2", "3"],
  ["2", "4"],
  ["3", "2"],
  ["3", "4"],
  ["4", "2"],
  ["4", "3"]
];

var roadsObj = arrayToObj(roadsArr);
console.log(roadsObj);
```

### 2) Test graph conditions

Next, I would think about the conditions you need to check to validate this as a bowtie, and test them one at a time.

#### Five nodes

You mentioned there should be exactly five nodes: we can test this by checking that there are exactly five keys.

```
/**
 * Check there are exactly five nodes
 * Returns true if 5 keys in roadsObj, false otherwise
 */
function hasFiveNodes(roadsObj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(roadsObj); // -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  return keys.length === 5;
}
```

#### Number of connections

You mentioned that one node should have four connections, while the others should each have two connections. Here is one way to check that:

```
/**
 * Check that each node has two connections, except one node with 4
 */
function hasValidNumConnections(roadsObj) {
  // extract array of values from object
  var valuesArr = Object.values(roadsObj); // -> [[0,1], [0,2] ... [2,3]]

  // map list of values into list of lengths
  var lenArr = valuesArr.map(x => x.length); // -> [2, 2, 4, 2, 2]

  // sort array of lengths
  var sortedLenArr = lenArr.sort(); // -> [2, 2, 2, 2, 4]

  // compare to desired string (because comparing arrays is tricky in JS)
  return sortedLenArr.toString() === "2,2,2,2,4";
}
```

#### Other conditions??

You probably will have to check some other conditions too-- for instance, you might have to check not just how many connections each node has, but *which* connections, to ensure the bowtie structure.

### 3) Putting it together

Seperating each condition check into its own function is likely not the most efficient strategy, but if efficiency is not crucial, it provides a nice structure to think through the problem and keep building on your solution. All together, it could look something like this:

```js
// ---------- helper function ----------

/**
 * Convert array of arrays into object
 * where {key=node, val=[array of connected nodes]}
 */
function arrayToObj(roadsArr) {
  var obj = {};
  roadsArr.forEach(function(pair) {
    var key = pair[0];
    var val = pair[1];
    if (obj[key] === undefined) {
      obj[key] = [val];
    } else {
      obj[key].push(val);
    }
  });
  return obj;
}

// ---------- validator functions ----------

/**
 * Check there are exactly five nodes
 * Returns true if 5 keys in roadsObj, false otherwise
 */
function hasFiveNodes(roadsObj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(roadsObj); // -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  return keys.length === 5;
}

/**
 * Check that each node has two connections, except one node with 4
 */
function hasValidNumConnections(roadsObj) {
  var valuesArr = Object.values(roadsObj); // -> [[0,1], [0,2] ... [2,3]]
  var lenArr = valuesArr.map(x => x.length);
  var sortedLenArr = lenArr.sort();
  return sortedLenArr.toString() === "2,2,2,2,4";
}

// ---------- main function ----------

/**
 * Check if given array represents a bowtie graph.
 */
function isBowtie(roadsArr) {
  // convert array to object
  var roadsObj = arrayToObj(roadsArr);

  // has exactly 5 nodes?
  if (!hasFiveNodes(roadsObj)) {
    return false;
  }
  console.log("> has 5 nodes");

  // has one node with 4 connections
  if (!hasValidNumConnections(roadsObj)) {
    return false;
  }
  console.log("> has valid number connections");

  // other checks??
  // ... insert here

  // if all pass, return true
  return true;
}

// ---------- testing ----------

roadsArr = [
  ["0", "1"],
  ["0", "2"],
  ["1", "0"],
  ["1", "2"],
  ["2", "0"],
  ["2", "1"],
  ["2", "3"],
  ["2", "4"],
  ["3", "2"],
  ["3", "4"],
  ["4", "2"],
  ["4", "3"]
];

var result = isBowtie(roadsArr);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great! If this is helpful to you, please upvote & mark as accepted, so I can have magic internet points :)

Comment: I've been not thinking about things as key-value pairs thus avoiding objects, which is really strange....lol. With enough loops and array methods you could probably do the same, but this so obviously better.

Comment: yikes, it looks like I don't have that option yet :|